# What is the asymptotic behavior of the number of primes of the form $2^n+1$ lower than a given N?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, asymptotics, approximation

I known that it is not known whether there are infinitely many prime numbers of the form $2^n+1$ or not, but is there any heuristic approach to its asymptotic behavior?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once I read this [beatiful article](http://www.utm.edu/staff/caldwell/preprints/Heuristics.pdf) of Caldwell, explaining basic heuristic related to this kind of open problems. I think it is what you are searching (in particular, see Conjecture 1.2).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I was searching a formula rather than an article with heuristic notions

Comment: @user3141592 I see your point, but heuristically you cannot expect a non-trivial asymptotic behaviour if there are only finitely many of them..

Comment: But what about Sophie Germain Primes? Heuristically, they have the asymptotic behaviour of $C\frac{n}{\ln{n}\ln{n}}$ and it is not known whether there are infinitely many of them or not

Comment: Indeed, it is expected that there infinitely many *because* its (heuristic) asymptotic behaviour diverges..

Comment: Then, can we conclude that the asymptotic behaviour of the number of Fermat Primes is not known?

Comment: What about $\#\{\text{Fermat primes} \le x\} = c$ as $x \to \infty$, for some $c \in \mathbf{N}$? :P

Comment: That would be a very nice theorem

Comment: Everyone agrees on that ;)